# Why the primitive unit cell is called primitive?

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, soft-question, crystals

while reading solid state physics I came about the concept of primitive and non-primitive [unit cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_cell) and I was wondering about why it is called primitive.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [English.se].  If you look in a good dictionary you'll find that one meaning of "primitive" is "not developed or derived from anything else; essential, fundamental."  (My definition's from the OED but I would expect you can find similar definitions elsewhere.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In complex crystalline solids, there may be more than one way to define a "unit cell" depending on how the constituent atoms are distributed in the repeating lattice positions. The simplest of those will be designated the *primitive*.